# Arrow function Vs String path in LoadChildren Route in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular-module

In the following code, beside the fact that in the first example, we need to import `productsModule` to the file, What is the difference between these two ways of loading a route lazily?

```
{ path: 'products', loadchildren: () => productsModule }
```

vs

```
{ path: 'products', loadchildren: 'app/products/products.module#ProductsModule' }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{ path: 'products', loadchildren: 'app/products/products.module#ProductsModule' }`

Its a deprecated way for lazy loaded modules for Angular 8.

loadChildren route configs should be changed from a string such as

`{ path: 'products', loadchildren: () => productsModule }`

https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#loadchildren-string-syntax

Comment: Be advised: LazyLoading using function is not supported by AOT compiling.

Comment: It does, just requires different syntax:


{ path: 'products', loadchildren: () => import('app/products/products.module').then(m => m.productsModule) }



see more details here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29959

Answer (score 1):

`loadChildren:string` [was deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/30073) in Angular 8.0.0 (2019-05-28).

> ES2017 dynamic `import()` is now supported by the Angular CLI and the
>   larger toolchain. This renders the `loadChildren: string` API largely
>   redundant, as `import()` is far more natural, is less error-prone, and
>   is standards compliant.

Except for that, the final result using both ways is the same (routes are lazily loaded, with a warning if the deprecated version is used).

However, to keep any project up to date, consider using

```
{ path: 'products', loadchildren: () => productsModule }
```

The deprecated version [may be removed in version 11](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#index).

See

- [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800-2019-05-28)
- [Commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/c61df39)

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think that the first case:

```
{ path: 'products', loadchildren: () => productsModule }
```

will not load module lazily, as `productsModule` has to be imported at the top of your `.ts` file (also no `.js` package is downloaded when accessing the route). You have to use the `import()` statement to make it lazy, example:

```
{ path: 'products', loadChildren: () => import('./products/products.module').then(m => m.productsModule) }
```

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

https://alligator.io/angular/lazy-loading/

*it should be `ProductsModule` instead of `productsModule`, according to string `'app/products/products.module#ProductsModule'`.